# Tab text is overflowing to next line in android

Tags: android, tabs

I have to use four tabs with tab text and icons.But when i put the fourth tab the text is overflowing to next line.I have to put all the tab text in single line not multiple.
These are the codes:-

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/custom_bg"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
       />
```

and the tabs contains:-

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tab"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
```

The below given the screenshot of my issue.The competition named tab is not showing the text in single line.When i hide     android:singleLine="true" text overflows to next line.How can i solve the issue ??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally i had found the answer.
Just put these 4 lines of code to your tab layout

```
app:tabPaddingBottom="0dp"
    app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
    app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
    app:tabPaddingTop="0dp"

 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/custom_bg"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabPaddingBottom="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingTop="0dp"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
       />
```

Comment: Great! That's the second time I was trying to solve that bug and luckily I have found you self-answered thread.

Comment: adding `app:tabPadding="0dp"`  works the same as the 4 lines